# Java - How do I call this method from the main() method in Java

Tags: java, list

I am still learning Java and would appreciate some assistance with this current problem: I am trying to call this static method from the main() method, however everything I try comes up with an error message. Thanks for any help.

This is my code:

```
public class Statistics {

    static double avgFor(List<Integer> list) {

        list.add(10);
        list.add(20);
        list.add(30);
        list.add(40);
        list.add(50);
        list.add(60);

        int max = list.get(0);

        for (int i : list) {
            max = max < i ? max : i;
        }

        return max;



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        avgFor();

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to read the error message. It tells you what is wrong.

Comment: You're returning an int when the method says double

Comment: It is useful when asking to paste the error you get too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the list creation and population to the main method, then pass it in:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); // create the list
    list.add(10); // populate it
    list.add(20);
    list.add(30);
    list.add(40);
    list.add(50);
    list.add(60);

    avgFor(list); // pass the list to your method
}
```

And remove the calls to `add()` from the `avgFor()` method:

```
static double avgFor(List<Integer> list) {
    int max = list.get(0);

    for (int i : list) {
        max = max < i ? max : i;
    }

    return max;
}
```

---

Note that you've reinvented the wheel:

```
int max = Collections.max(list);
```

Comment: I was trying to create a method to do this without using Collections, but thanks for your help!

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik please keep answers on this thread Java related

Answer (score 4):

Your method takes a List as argument. You cannot call the method without providing the argument.

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
avgFor(myList);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method has a parameter so when your are call it you have to pass the arguments for parameter also

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();

    avgFor(intList);
```